# Data-Migration vs VS2010 Database Project

Tags: sql-server-2008, version-control, data-migration, database-project

We are starting a complete overhaul of a project, a data-driven web app, and are looking at our options for version control of our database. We are a Microsoft house and use Visual Studio 2010 along with TFS. Current project uses a database project, but team is just looking at other options for new project. I have done some research on Migrator.NET and it seems like a solid versioning system.  I am just looking for opinions on which to use.  Pros and Cons of each possibly.

Thank you in advance

Also any links would be appreciated too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS database project as it is now is more about the storage of the schema in source control alongside your application code. Migrator.NET and other 'migrations' solutions such as Liquibase and DBDeploy are more based around the change management task of applying the appropriate changes to a target server.

Here at Red Gate we're hoping to improve the tooling in this area. If you're interested in learning about what we have so far, and telling us what needs to be done to solve your requirements please email me at david.atkinson at red-gate.com .